# Changing nvidia graphics card after installing 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and at present I am using the graphics card: GeForce 8400GS. I would like to remove this card and instead replace it with GTX GeForce  980 Ti which I have.

1. If I keep the current driver (for GeForce 8400GS), replace the
   graphics card then ubuntu won't boot up.
2. I can't install the new driver (driver for GTX GeForce 980 Ti)
   without removing the current card.

What is the recommended way to changing the cards and the respective graphic drivers?

Thanks for  your suggestions in advance.

Comment: Search Additional Drivers in dash and use it to revert to the open source drivers (`nouveau`). It should work fine with the old card but may not with the new one (but chances are that it will). If so, you may need the `nomodeset` parameter until you install the (latest) Nvidia drivers for the new card.

Comment: do what celticwarrior said but directly use nomodeset and change display drivers and reboot. no need to change drivers 2 times

Comment: You can install a new driver without replacing the card.

Comment: @CelticWarrior There is no need to boot with nomodeset as you can do it an easier way.

Comment: I tried @CelticWarrior's suggestion (without the nomodeset), it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install a new driver by

```
sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

Then turn off the computer and replace the card.